# Monitor server for changes to user accounts

Tags: bash, xubuntu

Very new here and very new to Linux. I need to write a bash script that will monitor a server for any changes to user accounts (added or deleted) and and email the changes. The server should be checked a couple of times a day. I'm thinking something along the lines a cron job that would run twice a day, run MD5 against the /etc/passwd file and if there is a change, somehow note the changes and email the changes.... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried; this isn't a homework service.

Comment: It would be easier if the user management on the server reported activity instead of needlessly polling for changes.

Answer (score 2):

Create two scripts on the server, one that adds a user and one that deletes a user. The scripts should perform the needed actions using the standard tools on your Unix, and then send an email or report in some other fashion about what was done (maybe to a logfile). *In fact*, I'd be slightly surprised if this wasn't logged already somewhere. Have a look at your logfiles in `/var` on the server.

This way you don't need to poll the server for changes to `/etc/passwd` and you would get an accurate description of exactly what has changed.

The polling solution you are looking for would potentially miss cases where, for example, a user was added, then removed again between consecutive polls.

Comment: All set guys.  Thanks for the input.  Here's what I came up with...                     #!/bin/bash
#You need to create a passwdck1.txt file from the /etc/passwd folder before running this script.
#
cp /etc/passwd passwdck2.txt
x=($(md5sum passwdck1.txt))
y=($(md5sum passwdck2.txt))
if [ "$x" = "$y" ]
then
echo "There are no changes to /etc/passwd"
exit
elif [ "$x" != "$y" ]
then
diff passwdck1.txt passwdck2.txt > changes/changes$(date "+%d%m%y%H:%M").txt
echo "Changes have been found in /etc/passwd and noted in changes(date).txt"
cp /etc/passwd passwdck1.txt
exit
fi

Comment: @morgro269 If `passwdck1.txt` is missing, you could let the script create it from the current `/etc/passwd`...

Comment: I think if I let it create passwdck1.txt every time that the script runs, it will miss changes.  That's why I have the script recreate passwdck1.txt only after finding changes....